# How to perform a preg_match() on this string?

Tags: php, preg-match

I am not good at doing `preg_match()`.Can someone help me create a `preg_match()` to retrieve that last parameter in the url.

PHP Code:

```
$url = "http://my.example.com/getThis";
$patern = ""; //need to create this

$result = preg_match($pattern, $url, $matches);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers of Muhammad Abrar Istiadi and AD7six are better ways to do the job than this and I strongly suggest using explode,

But to answer your question:

```
$url = "http://my.example.com/getThis";
$pattern = "/\/([^\/]*)$/";
preg_match($pattern, $url, $matches);
print_r($matches);`
```

Answer (score 3):

Retrieve the last parameter? Another way than using `preg_match`, split the `$url` at `/` character, then get the last element.

```
$url = "http://my.example.com/getThis";
$arr = explode("/", $url);

$result = $arr[count($arr) - 1];
```

`$result` will have the value `getThis`.

Comment: you can just use `$result = end($arr)` if you're going to use explode

Answer (score 1):

Don't use regular expressions when they aren't necessary (especially if they aren't your forte)

All you need is:

```
$lastSlash = strrpos($url, '/');
$result = substr($url, $lastSlash + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

**There is a simple PHP function parse_url() to handle this.**

Here are 3 different methods, the final, using the parse_url() function being the simplest.
The first is a simple Regular Expression.

The second is the same regular expression but adding key names for the resulting array.

The third is using PHP's parse_url() function which returns all your information much more simply, but does catch the '/' of the path.
    [path] => /getThis

**Code:**

```
echo "Attempt 1:\n\n";
$url = "http://my.example.com/getThis";
$pattern = "/(.*?):\/\/(.*?)\/(.*)/"; //need to create this
$result = preg_match($pattern, $url, $matches);
print_r($matches);

echo "\n\nAttempt 2:\n\n";
$url = "http://my.example.com/getThis";
$pattern = "/(?<scheme>.*?):\/\/(?<host>.*?)\/(?<path>.*)/"; //need to create this
$result = preg_match($pattern, $url, $matches);
print_r($matches);

echo "\n\nAttempt 3:\n\n";
$better = parse_url($url);
print_r($better);
```

**Results:**

Attempt 1:

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://my.example.com/getThis
    [1] => http
    [2] => my.example.com
    [3] => getThis
)


Attempt 2:

Array
(
    [0] => http://my.example.com/getThis
    [scheme] => http
    [1] => http
    [host] => my.example.com
    [2] => my.example.com
    [path] => getThis
    [3] => getThis
)


Attempt 3:

Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => my.example.com
    [path] => /getThis
)
```

Hope it helps ^^

Comment: all of the above examples rely on the path not containing a / to work e.g. none of the above code examples will return "getThis"  for "http://my.example.com/foo/getThis". It's not clear because of the wording of the question if that is infact the desired behavior or not

Comment: @AD7six - True, I did consider this, more often than not I require the full path, I was going with the assumption that if s/he required more I'd answer when the time came. Other wise I could answer 100 different answers all based on the same question.
>! h 
My scripts 1 & 2 also assume that there will always be a path, or at the very least a '/' after the domain.